# My paste function is not providing an accurate path to the file with csv data

Tags: r

In the code you'll see that it's an if/then function that will write a file directory depending on what operating system you have. This will run on Mac but when it sees I'm on windows I get this error:  Error in system(paste("/RTools/bin/wc -l \"", filename, "\"", sep = ""),  :    '/RTools/bin/wc' not found

I've tried debugging the function and as I run it, filename is being passed the correct csv file in the correct format. I believe I have an issue with the two back slashes going the wrong way and perhaps an extra quotation mark. Line 3-5 is where I believe my problem is.

```
function( filename ){
  if(.Platform$OS.type=="windows"){
    system.time({
      cmd<-system(paste("/RTools/bin/wc -l \"",filename, "\"",sep=""), intern=TRUE)
      cmd<-strsplit(cmd, " ")[[1]][1]
    })
    return(as.numeric(cmd) + 1)
  } else {
    system.time({
      cmd<-system(paste("wc -l \"",filename,"\" | awk \'{print $1}\'", sep=""), intern=TRUE)
      cmd<-strsplit(cmd, " ")[[1]][1]
    })
    return(as.numeric(cmd) + 1)
  }
}
```

I expect it to build the correct file path, it results in the error I listed.

Comment: What does `list.files("/RTools/bin/")` return? Are you sure that the Windows user has installed Rtools (it's not required for R)? Have they installed it to a different path?

Comment: May want to look into using `file.path()`.

Comment: R>list.files("/RTools/bin/")
character(0)

Comment: @MadMuke That means that folder doesn't exist on the windows machine. You can't execute a program that's not installed on that machine.

Comment: @MrFlick Understood, would I be able to install RTools and then copy it to my directory and have the script run the way it's written? I'm confused by the how the script switches from / to \.

Comment: R on windows will work just fine if you always use the forward-slash for path separators. BTW: I suggest you look into `shQuote` instead of trying to quote things yourself: it is much more readable, and it deals well with other issues you are not covering here.

Comment: Installing Rtools just for `wc` is a bit heavy, in my opinion. If you're working in programming languages, you might want `git` installed anyway ... and luckily, https://gitforwindows.org/ installation includes `wc`, as in `system(paste(shQuote("/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/wc.exe"), "--help"), intern=TRUE)`.